# How to display generated pdf as inline on browsers of Windows (10) OS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I can open an inline of the generated pdf on my Mac browsers Safari & Chrome.
But when I open it on Firefox & Chrome of my Windows 10 OS, it does not work. It always render as attachment/download.

```
render  pdf:      'show',
                template: 'show.pdf.haml',
                page_size: 'A4',
                layout:   'pdf_design.html.haml',
                show_as_html: params.key?('debug'),
                header: { html: { template: 'header.pdf.haml' } },
                footer: { html: { template: 'footer.pdf.haml' }, right: '[page] of [topage]' },
                margin: { left: 0, right: 0, top: 10 },
                dpi: '72',
                disposition: 'inline'
```

Versions I've used:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf',             '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.6'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '~> 0.12.3.0'
```

I've also posted an issue in the repo.
https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/690

Answer (score 1):

The browser settings may be overriding your preferences.

See [How to change browser download settings for PDF files](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001114.htm)

For example, Google Chrome:

By default Google Chrome should open a PDF in the browser and not save the PDF in the download folder to be opened by a PDF editor such as Adobe Reader. To change how Google Chrome treats PDF files in the browser follow the steps below.

1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Click on the Menu icon (Google Chrome Menu icon) in the top-right corner of the Window.
3. Click Settings.
4. Scroll down to the bottom of the Settings window and click Advanced.
5. In the Advanced section click Content Settings.
6. Click PDF documents.
7. Change the "Open PDFs using a different application" from the on position (blue) to the off position (grey).
8. Close the Settings tab and now any PDF should be opened in Chrome instead of being downloaded.

Tip: If you do want PDFs to be downloaded instead of opened in Chrome you can follow these steps and turn on the "Open PDFs using a different application" option.

Comment: My Chrome is already turned off that setting. Sorry, I should have mentioned about IDM. I've just figured out the problem is caused by the IDM, too. I remove "PDF" from "Automatically start downloading the following file types:" within "File Types" tab. PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: Good catch!  I was thinking it had to be something with the local browser :)